Upload .geojson API MAPBOX
Via the Mapbox web UI, I can upload a .geojson file (zonas1.geojson) to the dataset, export it to the tileset and then create a style with this data. How can I do the same procedure via API, sending the entire file 1, exporting it to the tileset and publishing a style?
I'm using Python.
import requests 
import boto3  
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError   do boto3
import json  

# Configurações iniciais
mapbox_username = 'xxxxxxx'  
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  
local_file_path = '/home/sonia/rede/mapbox/zonas1.geojson'  deseja enviar
tileset_name = 'xxxxxxxxxxx-1djoi'  

def get_s3_credentials():
    print("Searching credenciais S3...")
    url = f'https://api.mapbox.com/uploads/v1/{mapbox_username}/credentials?access_token={access_token}'
    
    response = requests.post(url)
    print(f"Asnswer credencials: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Credencials success!")
        return response.json()  
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error credencials  S3: {response.text}") 


def upload_to_s3(credentials, local_file_path):
    print("Upload to S3...")
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['accessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['secretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['sessionToken'],
    )
    
    s3 = session.resource('s3')  
    bucket_name = credentials['bucket']  
    object_key = credentials['key'] 

    try:
              s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_file(local_file_path, object_key)
        print(f"Upload succes bucket: {bucket_name}, chave: {object_key}")  
        return bucket_name, object_key  
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credencials not found.")  
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error upload S3: {e}")  

# Passo 3: Iniciar o Processo de Upload
def start_upload(bucket, key):
    print("Starting upload tileset...")
    url = f'https://api.mapbox.com/uploads/v1/{mapbox_username}?access_token={access_token}'
    upload_url = f"http://{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{key}"  # URL do arquivo no S3

    data = {
        "url": upload_url,
        "tileset": f"{mapbox_username}.{tileset_name}",
       
    }
    
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",  # Tipo de conteúdo
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"  # Controle de cache
    }
    
 
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    print(f": {response.status_code}, {response.text}")

   
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("Upload sucess!")  
        return response.json() 
    else:
        print(f": {response.text}") 

try:
    credentials = get_s3_credentials()  
    bucket, key = upload_to_s3(credentials, local_file_path)  
    upload_response = start_upload(bucket, key)  
    print(f": {upload_response}")  
except Exception as e:
    print(f": {e}")  

I can send the file to a tileset, but I can't send the same file to the dataset to have an effect on the style.
